# File Merger C++

Tags: c++, file, binary

I was developing an algorithm for a file spliter & merger, where I stumbled upon a problem on How do I merge the files(I split ) with their original extension(file format). I have an idea of writing the file format in the start of the very first chunk of split file (i-e if I have split a file in three files, then store the file format in 1.bij file). Will this idea work? Do you know any better idea, so please share with me.

Thanks

Comment: Keep the extension in the split file name? (`split.iso.1`, `split.iso.2`...)

Comment: I don't want to keep original file extension in split files !

Comment: Then store the info in the splits, or in a separate "metadata" file ... I don't really get what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You may include a header for each splitted file with its full filename, but also - for example - with original size, checksum and so on.

---

**Edit**: How to write text to binary stream

```
fstream f(/* initialize*/);

std::string s = "asdf";

// Store the size of text
auto size = s.size();
f.write(&size, sizeof(size));

// Store the string itself
f.write(s.c_str(), s.size());
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how can i add header to a file.

Comment: A header is just a bunch of bytes added to the beginning of the file with some useful data. Write it to the splitted files before the actual data. The algorithm will vary, depending on how does your splitting algorithm work. I cannot suggest anything unless you post some of your source codes.

Comment: Yeah thats my idea, as I mentioned above. But the question is how would i write text in binary mode..

Comment: The same way as anything else. A text is an array of characters, and every character is just a single byte value. You can either use 0 (for example bin[0]) value to denote the ending of sequence or precede it by its length (for example [3]bin).

Answer (score 1):

Why not let the user choose the filename with a command line argument ? You could use a `-o`  command line option. Bonus point for letting the user redirects to the standard output using the `-`filename. He could then pipe with another tool. For instance: `merger -o - part*.bin | tar zxvf -`